# Can the generalised Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma be proven without Gelfand theory?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $G$ be a locally compact abelian group, then the Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma states that for a function $f\in L^1(G)$, then the Fourier transform $\hat{f}\in \mathcal{C}_0(\hat{G})$.

Here local compactness means that every neighbourhood of a point $x\in G$ has a compact sub-neighbourhood. We also assume that $G$ is Hausdorff.

All the proofs I've seen for this use Gelfand theory, but I'm wondering is there a way of completing this proof directly?

Comment: These questions are not well-posed. I could take all the Gelhand theory results used, paste all the proofs underneath eachother, without ever explicitly mentioning Gelfand theory, and we'd have a "direct proof", wouldn't we?